# Detect selected file type in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-camera, onactivityresult

I'trying to open camera with video and photo.This code working correctly but in onActivityResult can't check file type. data.data is null
Here is a code

```
private fun openCamera() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    val takeVideoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    val chooserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)
    val contentSelectionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    val intentArray = arrayOf(takePictureIntent, takeVideoIntent)
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent)
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Choose an action")
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray)
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_STATUS_CODE)
}
```

onActivityResult code snippet

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    val selectedMediaUri = data?.data
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        when (requestCode) {
            GALERY_STATUS_CODE -> {
                
            }
            CAMERA_STATUS_CODE -> {
                val path = data!!.data!!.path
                if (path!!.contains("/video/")) {
                   
                } else if (path.contains("/images/")) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what's a wrong in my code?!
Thanks

Comment: getContentResolver().getType(uri) ?

Comment: @blackapps I don't understand your answer

Comment: better use the new 'OnActivityResultLauncher API'. It's the best when it comes to getting the result within activity or fragment or anything else.